# Eval awk command with single quotes

Tags: bash

I have a function "checkExist" that takes in a command and executes it based on whether or not the output file already exists. I pass a command like this, where file1 and file2 are just the names of output files that the commands create, so if they already exist it will ask if you want to overwrite, else it will skip:

```
checkExist file1 file2 command1 command2
```

In actual use like this:

```
checkExist 1.txt 2.txt "echo $1 | awk '$5 <= 10 {print $3, $4}'" "echo $2 | awk '$5 <= 10 {print $3, $4}'"
```

$1 and $2 above are inputs to the script "smartfilter.sh" containing the function checkExist within. So they are just file inputs.

Later in the checkExist function if the user types 'Y/y' to overwrite, or the files don't already exist then it will

```
eval $3 &
eval $4 &
wait
```

And I get an error like so:

```
awk:  >= 10 {print , }
awk:  ^ syntax error
awk:  >= 10 {print , }
awk:               ^ syntax error
awk:  >= 10 {print , }
awk:                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1:  >= 10 {print , }
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I know it is to do with the single quotations `'` around the awk and eval not parsing them correctly. I have tried `\'` but that doesn't work either. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkExist 1.txt 2.txt "echo $1 | awk '\$5 <= 10 {print \$3, \$4}'" "echo $2 | awk '\$5 <= 10 {print \$3, \$4}'"
```

Comment: The shell does variable substitution within double-quote strings, so it replaces the `$3` and `$4` get replaced with nothing (because those variables are unset). Your single quotes are contained within the double quotes, and so are ignored by the shell (but not by awk). I just quoted the dollars with `\` so the shell doesn't think they are variables. The shell does strip the `\` quotes though, so awk does the right thing. (If you wanted to have it quoted for both shell and awk, you'd have to say `\\\'`.) What can I say? Quoting levels are black magic.